# Windows 10 User Desktop, Documents, & Download folders disappear when redirected

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, desktop, user-profiles, folder-redirection

We have found that in Windows 10, a user's Desktop, Documents, and Download folders disappear from c:\users\%username%\ when redirected to a network share.

Nevertheless, these folders remain visible in File Explorer in the Desktop > [My Computer] tree just above the Windows (C:) node, along with their files.

Two questions, then:

- Why is this occurring and where on the filesystem are these network folders now mounted (or is the problem that NTFS is incapable of mounting a network share anywhere but to a drive letter).
- More importantly, how does one delete vestigal files and directories that appear on the user's Desktop but are absent from the network share, when attempts to delete them are met with an error stating that one must provide administrator permission to delete the folder, and then a subsequent error that folder access is denied.

Many thanks for any thoughts or solutions.

Comment: Do the user folder shortcuts under __This PC__ open to Network or local folders? What folders have "disappeared"?

Comment: The user folder shortcuts under This PC open to directories on a network share.  As noted (a) they appear in the My Computer / This PC tree and (b) they have been redirected to map to those directories by specifying them in the "Location" tab of their respective Properties dialog boxes.