# Redirected Windows 10 Desktop Directory Resisting View Configuration

Tags: mount, ntfs, user-profiles, desktop-customization, folder-redirection

A user's Desktop directory / shortcut has been redirected to a network share, by specifying that network share in the directory's Properties > Location tab.

As [noted](https://superuser.com/questions/1595625/windows-10-user-desktop-documents-download-folders-disappear-when-redirected), this causes the directory icon / mount point to disappear from c:\users\username.

The objective is to hide the ghost / greyed-out Recycle Bin and Desktop.ini icons.

The otherwise-enabled full-view Recycle Bin icon already has been removed by un-ticking its checkbox in Personalize > Themes > Desktop icon settings.

The problem is that configuring this folder to hide hidden files, folders, and drives also configures the entire filesystem.

Ordinarily, it is possible to configure view settings folder-wise without those settings affecting the rest of the filesystem.

Unfortunately, this particular folder is resisting configuration.

Perhaps this is a consequence of the folder's / mount point's disappearance from c:\users\username, effectively concealing the mount point and preventing its configuration.  If so, perhaps locating the new mount point so as to configure it would work.  No amount of research has yielded information about where this new mount point might be, however.

Regardless, the question is how to implement folder-specific view settings for a redirected desktop folder.

Many thanks in advance for any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: View settings such as icon mode, sorting, grouping, and column choice/order are saved on a per-folder basis. But Show/hide Hidden items, along with all the other options in the checklist on the `View` tab of hte `Folder Options` dialog, affect all `Explorer` windows on a per-user basis. The same holds true for window position.

Comment: When a user's folders *aren't* re-directed, they are actual folders under `c:\Users\username`, not mount points. They are the *targets* of the `namespace junctions` you see under `This PC`. The targets for these and other per-user known folders are found in the registry under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WIndows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`, not  `c:\Users\username`.

Comment: As far as the `desktop.ini` icons, do the open the files when double-clicked or do you receive an error message? What are your effective permissions for the files?

Comment: Double-clicking on the ghost Recycle Bin icon opens Windows/File Explorer to the Recycle Bin.  Double-clicking on the ghost Desktop.ini icon opens the document in Notepad, and it has a [.ShellClassInfo] key entry.  File > Save As reveals that the file is in c:\users\public\public desktop.  Configuring that folder's view settings also configures the entire filesystem.

Comment: All that file does is provide the display name "Public Desktop" to the folder. If you open a Command Propmpt or PowerShell to `c:\Users\Public`, you'll see the actual file system foldernames aren't prefixed with "Public". If you have adequate permissions, you can safely delete the `desktop.ini` file without any ill effects -- only the name displayed for the containing folder will be changed to the actual folder name: "Desktop".

Comment: Thanks-that was helpful in removing the desktop.ini file.

Comment: That leaves the ghost / greyed-out Recycle Bin icon.  Any thoughts on how to remove it?

Comment: I read your post as saying the Recycle Bin was effectively hidden by un-checking it in the `Desktop Icons` dialog. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, that is not the case.  As noted in the OP, the objective is to remove the "ghost" / greyed-out icons.  To start, two Recycle Bin icons appeared, the "normal" one and a greyed-out "ghost" counterpart, the latter of which is the subject of this post.  The former was effectively hidden by un-checking in Personalize > Themes > Desktop icon settings, which I wanted to be clear had been removed by ordinary means.  The remaining issue is the greyed-out Recycle Bin icon to which I first referred.

Comment: OK. Didn't realize you had two icons to start with. If you opt to show the "normal" REcycle Bin via the `Dekstop Icons` dialog, are the `Properties` dialogs for the icons identical? The default icon only has a single, specialized `General` tab.

Comment: Windows couldn't do it.  Linux could.  sudo rm -r '$Recycle Bin' and you're done.

Comment: LOL. A competent Windows user or even a novice who gave complete information could have.

Comment: I don't follow.  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to delete the shadow / ghost Recycle Bin icon / directory from the file server directory shared to Windows.

Windows isn't up to the task but, no surprise, Linux is:

```
sudo rm -r '$Recycle Bin'
```

is all it takes.